# How to disable form button until function has fully complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So everything in script works perfectly. However there is an issue in this part of the code:

```
var min = 1;
while (min < 200) {
    var max = min + 30;

    scan(fruitID, min, max);

    var min = max;
}
```

What I want from this loop:

1. Computes `max` value
2. Calls `scan()` function
3. Waits until the ajax in scan has successfully gotten the data, and displayed it up on the screen.
4. Computes `min` value
5. Repeats the loop

The mistake is in step 3. It doesn't wait for ajax to get the data back and process it. It just straight away repeats the loop. How do I make the loop wait until the `scan()` function has fully finished.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


    $('#submit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $("#submit").attr("disabled", true);
    $("#submit").html("Verifying Username");
    var fruitName = $("#fruit-name").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "verify-input.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {fruitName:fruitName},
        success : function(data){
            if (data.code == 200){
                $("#submit").html("Running Scan");
                var fruitID = data.fruitId;
                //alert("Fruit ID: " + fruitID);

                var min = 1;
                while (min < 200) {
                    var max = min + 30;

                    scan(fruitID, min, max);

                    var min = max;
                }

            } else {
                $("#submit").attr("disabled", false);
                $("#submit").html("Submit");
                $(".display-error").html("<ul>"+data.msg+"</ul>");
                $(".display-error").css("display","block");
            }
        }
    });


    });
});

function scan(vFruitId, min, max) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "scanner.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {vFruitId: vFruitId, min: min, max: max},
        success : function(data){
            data.forEach((item, idx) => {
              $("#results").append(`
                <div class="fruit-item" data-item="${idx}">
                    <div class="f-calories">calories: ${item.sweetness}</div>
                    <div class="f-sweetness">sweeteness: ${item.calories}</div>
                    <div class="f-bitterness">bitterness: ${item.bitterness}</div>
                </div>
              `);
      })
        }
    });

}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="fname">Fruit (only correct input is: banana)</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fruit-name" name="fruit" value="banana"><br>
  <button type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<div id="results">
</div>
```

Comment: since scan is asynchronous, you'll need to handle the asynchrony - since jquey ajax returns a promise-like object, you could use that promise. make success callback `async function (data)` ... then `await scan(fruitID, min, max);` and finally in `scan` you `return $.ajax({`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

note: your original code does not re-enable the form button, so the question title is a bit misleading

The solution is to use the Promise-like object returned by $.ajax

The following code uses *arrow notation* like in the question, but does not use `async/await` so would work anywhere the code in the question works

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#submit').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $("#submit").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#submit").html("Verifying Username");
        var fruitName = $("#fruit-name").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "verify-input.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                fruitName: fruitName
            },
            success: function (data) { 
                if (data.code == 200) {
                    $("#submit").html("Running Scan");
                    var fruitID = data.fruitId;
                    //alert("Fruit ID: " + fruitID);

                    function runscan(min) {
                        return scan(fruitID, min, min+30)
                        .then(() => {
                            min = min + 30;
                            if (min < 200) {
                                return runscan(min);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    runscan(1)
                    .then(() => {
                        // all done here
                    });

                } else {
                    $("#submit").attr("disabled", false);
                    $("#submit").html("Submit");
                    $(".display-error").html("<ul>" + data.msg + "</ul>");
                    $(".display-error").css("display", "block");
                }
            }
        });

    });
});

function scan(vFruitId, min, max) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "scanner.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            vFruitId: vFruitId,
            min: min,
            max: max
        },
        success: function (data) {
            data.forEach((item, idx) => {
                $("#results").append(`
                <div class="fruit-item" data-item="${idx}">
                    <div class="f-calories">calories: ${item.sweetness}</div>
                    <div class="f-sweetness">sweeteness: ${item.calories}</div>
                    <div class="f-bitterness">bitterness: ${item.bitterness}</div>
                </div>
              `);
            })
        }
    });

}
```

Alternatively, using async/await, the main `success` code can be written

```js
success: function(data) {
  if (data.code == 200) {
    $("#submit").html("Running Scan");
    (async function() { // `success` can't be async, because jquery doesn't like that
      var fruitID = data.fruitId;
      //alert("Fruit ID: " + fruitID);
      var min = 1;
      while (min < 200) {
        await scan(fruitID, min, min + 30);
        min = min + 30;
      }
    })();
  } else {
    $("#submit").attr("disabled", false);
    $("#submit").html("Submit");
    $(".display-error").html("<ul>" + data.msg + "</ul>");
    $(".display-error").css("display", "block");
  }
}
```

Important note: you still MUST `return $.ajax` in `function scan` as per first code snippet

Comment: Can you show me how to do this with a while loop instead? I'm not really understanding the `=>` syntax

Comment: firstly, you can't use while loop with asynchronous calls unless you use async/await .... anyway, you use the `=>` syntax in your code, so why don't you understand it? - where I've used `() => {` use `function() {` basically the same thing in this code ... and the second snippet that uses async/await uses your while loop (written a little more succinctly) anyway

Comment: Could you explain the async and await one. I put async in front of my first function (as you shown above) and the await on when I call the scan function. I return the `$ajax` in the scan function. However, I can see that it never makes a call to my `scanner.php`

Comment: check your browser console - are you sure you tagged the success callback function `async` - saying you put it in front of your first function suggests you did it wrong

Comment: There is nothing i my console.

Comment: does `$("#submit").html("Running Scan");` execute - add some console logs through your code to see what is and isn't running

Comment: It does not execute

Comment: hmmm, and there's no errors at all in your browser developer tools console - but the first request does take place

Comment: The first request (to `verify-input.php`) takes place. Then it doesn't execute `running scan` text and there is no errors. before async and await, it worked fine

Comment: then don't use async/await version, try the first version - not sure why async/await would fail to work, but then, jQuery is jQuery and prone to break for no reason

Comment: @Jackie - I've updated the async/await version - jquery probably doesn't like the success callback to be `[object AsyncFunction]` rather than `[object Function]` - so I've put the async/await stuff inside an IIFE